# Conditional Tags in Wordpress: How to Run a Different JS File Depending on Page ID or Title

Tags: javascript, wordpress, conditional-statements

I want to run a different external JavaScript file for each WordPress page, depending on the page ID.

If Page ID is [1], run somescript.js
if Page ID is [15], run someotherscript.js
if Page ID is [195], run yetanotherscript.js

if default, run defaultscript.js

Could someone please show me how this is done in WordPress with Conditional Tags?

Best regards,

Dimitri Vorontzov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having tried the suggested solutions, I couldn't make them work. I'm sure Chris's advice is perfectly solid and it's me who's doing something wrong, but so far I had to resort to a duct tape solution:

I created a custom page template for every version of the script I wanted to run, and assigned a separate template to each page. Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

You should NEVER echo script call to the header.  Your going to break plugins screw up the dependencies and load multiple copies of scripts if you do it that way.

Create a function in functions.php

```
 add_action( 'init', 'dim_load_scripts' );
function dim_load_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'my-first-script', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ). '/path/to/script.js', array( 'jquery' ), true);  
    //the jquery is only needed if it is a depencency
    wp_register_script( 'my-second-script', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ). '/path/to/script.js', array( 'jquery' ), true); 
    wp_register_script( 'my-third-script', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ). '/path/to/script.js', array( 'jquery' ), true);  
    wp_register_script( 'my-fourth-script', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ). '/path/to/script.js', array( 'jquery' ), true);   

  if (is_page( 22 ) ) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'my-first-script' );
  } elseif 
     (is_page ( 33 ) ) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'my-second-script' );
  } elseif 
     (is_page ( 33 ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-third-script' );
  } else 
   if (is_page ( 33 ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-fourth-script' );
    }
}
```

### The code in your comments had syntax errors.  Corrected:

```
function dim_load_scripts() { 
wp_register_script( 'homescript.js', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ). '/supersized/js/homescript.js', array( 'jquery' ), true); 
wp_register_script( 'defaultscript.js', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ). '/supersized/js/defaultscript.js', array( 'jquery' ), true);

      if (is_home() ) {
     wp_enqueue_script( 'homescript.js' );   
     } elseif(is_page ( 11 ) ) { 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'defaultscript.js' );     
    }
    }
```

Also this has to be in functions.php.  I won't work in wp-header.php

Comment: Thank you Chris, this looks like what I wanted. Just to make sure I get it right: to make the last script execute by default, should I just leave the last conditional tag without argument, like this: is_page() – or how does it work?

Comment: Tried it as it is, and it kills my WordPress. I must be doing something wrong. Could you please comment Chris, something definitely isn't working!

Comment: @Dimitri I screwed up the syntax.  Been up too late tonight.  Try again I fixed it.

Comment: Tried it, same result. I add this at the bottom of functions.php.  add_action( 'init', 'dim_load_scripts' );
function dim_load_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'homescript.js', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ). '/supersized/js/homescript.js', array( 'jquery' ), true);  
    wp_register_script( 'defaultscript.js', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ). '/supersized/js/defaultscript.js', array( 'jquery' ), true);   

  if (is_home() ) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'homescript.js' );
  } else 
   if (is_page ( 11 ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'defaultscript.js' );
    }
}

Comment: @Chris If it's a custom, self-written script, be so kind as to explain how it's going to get loeaded multiple times by echoing it. Curious as to what explanation you can come up with. Pretty bold statement without any background...

Comment: The question never mentioned it was a personal script or if it depened on jQuery.  Even if is personal and has no depencies with wp_enqueue_script will output it with the block of other script calls after all css calls.

Comment: Nope, Chris. The edited code doesn't work for me. I must be doing something wrong. I add that code at the very end of the functions.php file.  I have the "supersized" folder in the main directory of the theme, "js" folder inside the "supersized" folder, and both scripts inside the "js" folder – so the paths seem to be correct. Page ID is correct. And yet, nothing happens. Advice please?